# 403 Forbidden when trying to change discord status bot (delphi)

Tags: delphi, discord

I have a bot written in Delphi. It does a great job of sending and reading messages and handing out roles.
But as soon as I want to change his status, I get an error 403 Forbidden.

```
    RESTRequest1.Client.BaseURL := 'https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/settings';
    RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    RESTRequest1.AddBody('{"status":"dnd"}', TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure "PRESENCE INTENT" and "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT" is enabled in the bot settings on the Discord Developer Portal.

(https://discord.com/developers/applications)

After selecting your bot, navigate to the "Bot" section. Scroll down to the "Privileged Gateway Intents" section and make sure the "Presence Intent" and "Server Members Intent" are enabled then save the changes.

Comment: These settings are enabled. He has an administrator role on the server.